# How to solve cubic polynomial algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

I have this characteristic equation from a matrix:

$$ 0 = \lambda^3 - \frac{3a^2}{4}\lambda - \frac{1}{4}a^3$$

Where a is some constant.

I have no idea how to go about doing this by hand, I know the answer. I feel like I just missed this in my background of learning mathematics. Any guidance would be appreciated and in general how to solve problems like this.

Comment: [Cardano's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#math_Cardano's_formula) in general. For your equation you have a solution that is rational $\lambda=a$. Divide the polynomial by $\lambda-a$ to get a quadratic polynomial, which you can solve using the [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). After the division the quadratic polynomial turns out to be $(\lambda +a/2)^2$. Therefore, the other two solutions are $-a/2$ with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: @user647486 How did you find that the solution is a? Using Cardano's formula?

Comment: It is $\frac{a}{1}$, which is a divisor $a$ of the constant term $-\frac{1}{4}a^3$ divided by a divisor $1$ of the leading term $1$. This is applying the [theorem about rational roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which allows you to search if there are any rational solutions.

Comment: @user647486 I see, would you have to consider -a ?

Comment: Would you be able to write out the steps for dividing the polynomial?

Comment: You can divide by $a^3$ to get a cubic in $\frac \lambda a$.  Then the rational root theorem says the rational roots are among $\pm \frac 14, \pm \frac 12, \pm 1$.  That is not many to try and finds $1$ to be a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the cubic formula, $$ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d=0,\ x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\left(b^{3}-4.5abc+13.5a^{2}d\right)^{2}-\left(b^{2}-3ac\right)^{3}}-\left(b^{3}-4.5abc+13.5a^{2}d\right)}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\left(b^{3}-4.5abc+13.5a^{2}d\right)^{2}-\left(b^{2}-3ac\right)^{3}}+\left(b^{3}-4.5abc+13.5a^{2}d\right)}-b}{3a}$$ which reduces down greatly to give $$λ=a$$